# Parse JSON like VARCHAR Column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a VARCHAR column called `TAG` within a SQL database with the data looking like the example below.

**Example**:

```
{
  "list":[
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"aa1212dg3232",
           "name":"Joe Doe",
           "postScore":9000,
           "url":”google.com"
        }
     },
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"1111jjdjdjsdj11",
           "name":"Jane Doe",
           "postScore":12222,
           "url":"yahoo.com"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Since it is not a JSON column, I am having difficulty parsing through the column to get the postScore value.

I have tried to convert this from a `VARCHAR` to `Variant` datatype so that I can do something like the following to get the

```
SELECT d.TAGS['list']['item']['postScore']::string as PostScore
FROM data d;
```

Any help on how I can go about getting that postScore value from this Varchar column would be appreciated!

Comment: For a start, as `list` is an array, you need to either 'flatten' the array to one element per row *(so you can extract data from each array element to a different output row in SQL)*, or you need to specify which element you want to read from.  I suggest starting from here, in the docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `parse_json` and a `flatten`. Note that your JSON has a problem with it. Notice that your first quote character at the beginning of the word `google` is a weird double-quote that may cause you problems: `"url":”google.com"` - `”` is different from `"`.

Anyway, assuming that your quote was an error with your copy-paste and not actually a problem with your actual JSON then you can do it like this:

**Query**

```sql
select
    value:item:postScore
from test_table,
     lateral flatten(input => parse_json(col1):list)

;
```

**Sample table I used**

```sql
create or replace transient table test_table as (
    select
        column1::varchar as col1
    from
    values ('{
  "list":[
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"aa1212dg3232",
           "name":"Joe Doe",
           "postScore":9000,
           "url":"google.com"
        }
     },
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"1111jjdjdjsdj11",
           "name":"Jane Doe",
           "postScore":12222,
           "url":"yahoo.com"
        }
     }
  ]
}')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a CTE as an example input:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT '{
  "list":[
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"aa1212dg3232",
           "name":"Joe Doe",
           "postScore":9000,
           "url":"google.com"
        }
     },
     {
        "item":{
           "id":"1111jjdjdjsdj11",
           "name":"Jane Doe",
           "postScore":12222,
           "url":"yahoo.com"
        }
     }
  ]
  }' as str
)
```

You just need to flatten the array after parsing the string to JSON:

```
SELECT y.value:item:postScore::varchar
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>parse_json(str):list) y;
```